# Change default key combination for backslash character on a German Mac keyboard?

Tags: mac, keyboard

As pressing `⌥⇧7` keys simultaneously to type a backslash character (`\`) on a German iMac (macOS High Sierra 10.13.4) keyboard is rather unhandy and painful I would like to know whether it is possible to change the key combination to something different, like `⌃7`? Is there any way to achieve this **without using any third-party application**?

Comment: The only native way to do something like that is via system preferences/keyboard/text/replace with, unless a particular app has its own feature for creating keyboard shortcuts for characters  (like Word 2016 > Insert >  Advanced Symbol > Keyboard Shortcut)

Comment: Unfortunately - as you stated - this only works in some applications such as Mail. In Terminal or other third-party CLI-applications "replace with" does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

If your macOS version is recent enough (Monterey or perhaps also Big Sur), you will find Apple has added an input source called German Standard where backslash is on Option ß.