# Backslash on German MacBook Keyboard

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

I've recently bought a 2019 MacBook Pro with a German keyboard and am encountering some difficulties. Previously, I had been a windows user and my frequent use of Latex requires me to use backslash quite a bit in programming. I really enjoyed the Windows feature of 'Alt'+9 (Might not be 9, but you get the idea) being a backslash, yet on Apple with a German keyboard, the procedure is quite cumbersome.
I saw the feature of shortcuts, but as far as I can discern, this only refers to Apps, not the keyboard as a whole. I saw this unanswered question [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/321923/change-default-key-combination-for-backslash-character-on-a-german-mac-keyboard) and later found the platform Ukulele, which seems very cumbersome though. Is there any way to be able to get a backslash pressing just two keys without Ukulele?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Easy way to remap non-modifier keys on Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/281405/easy-way-to-remap-non-modifier-keys-on-mac)

Comment: The input source called German Standard has \ on Alt/Option ß.

Comment: @TomGewecke This literally made my day. Thank you very much